# Unable to find changed User Defined Columns at runtime with IdeaBlade

Tags: devforce

I was following the IdeaBlade instructional unit for User Defined Columns, I have created the following method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetUnknownColumns(PersistenceManager pManager, Type pType)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorList.Reset(pType);
        var definedDescriptors = PropertyDescriptorList.Get(pType);
        pManager.Clear();
        pManager.InitializeSchema(pType);
        EntityTable uddTable = pManager.GetTable(pType);
        foreach (DataColumn col in uddTable.Columns)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = definedDescriptors.Find(col.ColumnName);

            if (prop == null)
                yield return col;
        }
    }
```

Note: `pType` is assumed to be an `IdeaBlade.Persistence.Entity`.
This code works great, except if I make changes to the entity/table that `pType` points to during runtime, this code will no pick up the new columns. Furthermore, if I remove a column it will still appear in `uddTable.Columns`. What am I doing incorrect?

**EDIT**
Fixed a typo (manager -> pManager).
I have also figured out the issue, I was modifying the table pType points to through sql and not through the PM, which I believe to be the cause of the issue. I fixed it by adding `EntityTypeInfo.GetPrototypeTable(pType).IsSchemaInitialized = false;` before the InitializeSchema call

Comment: How are you modifying the EntityTable?  Some background - each PM holds a DataSet containing the EntityTables/DataTables for each type.  When you clear the PM and call InitializeSchema that will go back to the DB to find the column info.  If the new columns are in the DB, then also look at the EntityTypeInfo class - it maintains a prototype table for each Entity type and may be holding the "old" info.  Note that your snippet here is using a different PM on the GetTable call - I assume it's a typo, but if not also take a look at that.

Comment: You are correct, I meant to use pManager for the GetTable call, that was merely a typo. It appears that the Sql Table is modified using a DynamicEntity with a PassthruRdbQuery. This query then modifies the table which is probably why the EntityTable information isn't updating like I would expect it to. I've managed to get it to work by adding `EntityTypeInfo.GetPrototypeTable(pType).IsSchemaInitialized = false` before `InitializeSchema`. Thanks, I appreciate the help.